# Xcode: Why doesn't this code call the action in another class?

Tags: xcode, class, action

I have two view controllers. In one of them I have a `UITextField` within a `UITableViewCell`. What I want is to call a action in another view controller when the `UITextField` is being edited. In the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

I use this code to call the action:

```
[TextFieldText addTarget:Viewcontroller1 action:@selector(ApplyAllObjectsSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

The action is in `Viewcontroller1` and it looks like this:

```
- (void)ApplyAllObjectsSettings {
    NSLog(@"Test");
    // Test
}
```

I have inserted the action in the .h file.

The weird thing is that I have used almost the same code earlier and it worked fine. I think the only difference is that the view controller the `UITextfield` is in is shown from `Viewcontroller1` by `presentmodalviewcontroller`. and where the code that worked was presented it was by addsubview. Don't know if this have anything to say.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: My initial guess is that either `TextFieldText` and/or `Viewcontroller1` are NULL at the point the `addTarget` call is made; I'd double check those first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong.  With the trailing colon in `@selector(ApplyAllObjectsSettings:)` the method you want is not going to be called because it takes no arguments.  `@selector(ApplyAllObjectsSettings:)` is very different from `@selector(ApplyAllObjectsSettings)`.  Either change your `ApplyAllObjectsSettings` method to this: `- (void)ApplyAllObjectsSettings:(id)sender`, or your selector to this: `@selector(ApplyAllObjectsSettings)`.

So, either do this:

```
[TextFieldText addTarget:Viewcontroller1 action:@selector(ApplyAllObjectsSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
// ...
- (void)ApplyAllObjectsSettings:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Test");
    // Test
}
```

Or this:

```
[TextFieldText addTarget:Viewcontroller1 action:@selector(ApplyAllObjectsSettings) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
// ...
- (void)ApplyAllObjectsSettings {
    NSLog(@"Test");
    // Test
}
```

---

From the capitalization of the syntax, it appears that your target is a class name.  The `addTarget:` parameter needs to be an instance of an object, not the class name.

```
Viewcontroller1 *vc1 = [[Viewcontroller1 alloc] initWithBlahBlah...];
[TextFieldText addTarget:vc1 action:@selector(ApplyAllObjectsSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```